# Swift: How to access value of "_" parameter?

Tags: swift, function, parameters

I noticed that this is a valid function in Swift:

```
func test(_:String) {
    print("How do I access '_'?")
}
```

How do I access the parameter?

**EDIT**
Additional question, is there a valid/good use-case for this?

Comment: Just replace it by `func test(str:String)` ... If you want to access the parameter then you should not call it `_`.

Comment: @MartinR, Of course you can do that but I meant if you use _ instead of any parameter name like "str", how do you access the value of _.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The first parameter has an empty external name by default. – Or are you thinking of additional parameters, as in `test(a: String, _ b: String)` ?

Comment: @MartinR, no, I'm curious if there's a way to access the value of `_`. I just noticed this as I was modifying the parameters of function that I was writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How do I access the param?

You don't. Using that syntax you are explicitly saying you don't want to access the param.

### Use case

Lets say you have access to a very powerful async API like the following.

```
func theAnswerToLife(success:(answer: String) -> (), failure:(error: NSError) -> ())
```

> yes, of course I am keeping the implementation secret

Now if the function `theAnswerToLife` does find the answer it calls the `success` closure, otherwise `failure` is invoked.

You are forced to pass both closure/functions but you are really interested only in the `answer`, if something goes wrong you don't mind about the actual error.

So you could define

```
func tellEveryone(answer: String) {
    print("The answer to life is " + answer)
}

func badNews(_:NSError) {
    print("Something went wrong, we will try again tomorrow")
}
```

`badNews` can be passed as second param to `theAnswerToLife` and who in future will look at the code will immediately understand that `badNews` does not care about the received param.

```
theAnswerToLife(tellEveryone, failure: badNews)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is so called *wildcard matching pattern*, and it is introduced just for the sake of not being able to use a parameter, because you just do not care about it.

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID420):

> A *wildcard pattern* matches and ignores any value and consists of an underscore (_). Use a wildcard pattern when you don’t care about the values being matched against.

You have to use a proper identifier if you need to access the argument value.

---

Regarding updated part of your question.  I do not know why would you want to do this (just a wild idea), but if you want to completely hide argument names of a method of a `public` class but still be able to use them in `private` sub-class, you can do something like:

```
public class Foo {
    func test(_: String, _: Int) {
        print("[Ignored]")
    }
}

private class Bar: Foo {
    override func test(stringArgument: String, _ intArgument: Int) {
        print("\(stringArgument) \(intArgument)")
    }
}
```

Anyone external, using your library, would use abstract `Foo` without knowing parameter names of `test` method.

Comment: So, it means if it is _, there is no way to access the value?

Comment: @yoninja No, the whole reason of `_` is to discard the value

Comment: @yoninja, there should be no such way.  If there is, it would be a bug or ugly hack.

Answer (score 1):

The point of using _ is that you are not interested in using the parameter. An example usage is this

```
if let _ = someVariable as? String {
   //Do stuff here if someVariable is a string
   //But I'm not interested in accessing the unwrapped value, so I set the unwrapped variable name to _
}
```